# Identify derived class and instance in one way

Tags: c#, .net

I don't really find a good title for this question but it goes as follows. I find myself in a situation where I want to identify a class and an instance of the class. The solution I have is to use a `const` value for the class and a property that returns that `const` value for the instance.

I don't know if there is a better solution. It feels a bit strange that I need two ways to identify and just reuse the value. Is there a better way?

Pseudo code below. In the real application there will be more classes that derive from the base class and the `objects` list will contain instances of these as well. Deserialization happens at startup, serialization at shutdown after after the list has been altered due to user activity.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Base> objects = new List<Base>();
    List<string> serializationIds = new List<string>();
    // SerializationIds initialized somehow
    foreach (var serializationId in serializationIds)
    {
        switch(serializationId)
        {
            // Identify class
            case Derived.SerializationIdText:
                objects.Add(new Derived());
                break;
        }
    }

    // add remove objects

    foreach (var item in objects)
    {
        // Identify instance
        string serializationId = item.SerializationId;
        // Do something with serializationId;
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public string SerializationId { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public const string SerializationIdText = "DatabaseExplorer";
    public Derived()
    {
        SerializationId = SerializationIdText;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I find myself in a situation where I want to identify a class and an instance of the class." -- let's go deeper. Why do you want to do this? Maybe there's a better way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Basically this is my problem. The real application is more complex but the basic problem is this serialization issue where I need to identify what I serialize to be able to deserialize.

Comment: So you're storing an ID (for the class) and the data (for the instance) in the stream at serialization time, and -- at deserialization time -- you need to magically turn that ID and the data back into an instance of the correct class...?

Comment: That's the simplified version indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping twice, why not perform the functions of the second loop withint the first the first?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Base> objects = new List<Base>();
    List<string> serializationIds = new List<string>();
    // SerializationIds initialized somehow
    foreach (var serializationId in serializationIds)
    {
        switch(serializationId)
        {
            // Identify class
            case Derived.SerializationIdText:
                 string serializationId = item.SerializationId;
                 // Do something with serializationId;
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

You might be able to refactor out the code within the switch statement, too, so you could have something like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Base> objects = new List<Base>();
    List<string> serializationIds = new List<string>();
    // SerializationIds initialized somehow
    foreach (var serializationId in serializationIds)
    {
         string serializationId = item.SerializationId;
         // Do something with serializationId;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're oversimplifying the example. Maybe I was not clear enough in that there will be more derived classes. I'll update the question.